# Tree shaking with TSDX - typescript with rollup

Tags: reactjs, webpack, rollup, tree-shaking, tsdx

I have a **Monorepo** which is created using **yarn workspaces** and bundled with **TSDX**.

**Note:** TSDX is Typescript + Rollup

My Monorepo has 2 folders inside packages,

- **App** (private)        - It's a CRA - create react app application, this application is consuming Components package
- **Component**  - It's a package using TSDX for bundling

Component package has 3 components exported

- logOne
- logTwo
- FilePreviewer
  **Note :** FilePreviewer component is using a external package **(react-pdf)**

*Exported file from components package has following code*

```
export function logOne () {
  return "Rendered logOne()";
}
export function logTwo() {
  return "Rendered logTwo()";
}

export * from "./filePreviewer";
```

> I'm importing only logTwo() inside **App**,
>
> **Expected behavior** App should have only logTwo,
>
> **Actual behavior** logTwo and it is importing FilePreviewer dependent package **(react-pdf)**

I have created a public Github repository to replicate above scenario,
[Click here for Github repository link](https://github.com/palani-kamaraj/tsdx_monorepo)

> **STEPS TO FOLLOW**
>
> - Clone the repository
> - yarn install
> - yarn build - *build Component package*
> - yarn start - *start App package*
> - yarn analyze - *analyze the build and show bundle size*